Satisfying $Sd(S)$ modular conditions with $O(S)$ points
I was trying to solve some problem and reduced it to the one I describe below. For now I am only interested in this reduced version.

For a given positive integer $S$, consider the following set of conditions:
$$\bigcup_{AB=S}\bigcup_{i = 0...A-1\\j = 0...B-1}\begin{cases} x = i\mod A\\y = j\mod B \end{cases}$$
Is there a set of $O(S)$ points $(x, y)$ such that every condition is satisfied by at least one point?

Essentially, we want to color $O(S)$ cells of an infinite grid, so that when "wrapping" the grid into a rectangle of area $S$, it always ends up fully colored. Below is an example for $S=4$.

My reasoning is that it should be impossible, because the number of conditions grows superlinearly as $Sd(S)$, where $d(S)$ is the number of divisors of $S$. Moreover, the conditions seem to be quite independent because the divisors can be rather arbitrary. However, I don't know how to prove this formally or if this is even true. Do you have any ideas how to tackle the problem? What if we consider $AB \leq S$?

Let $S=p^n$ for a prime $p$.  For $k=0,\cdots, p^n-1$, let $x_k=k$.  Write $k$ as an $n$ digit number base $p$ and reverse the digits (including leading $0$'s up to $n$'th digit) and let $y_k$ be the resulting value.
Then for $A=p^r, B=p^s$ with $r+s=n$ we have the last $r$ digits of $k$ give you $x_k \mod A$ and the first $s$ digits give you $y_k \mod B$.
Apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem to combine solutions for $p_i^{n_i}$ to a single solution for $S=(p_1^{n_1})\cdots (p_l^{n_l})$.
By the way, your solution for $S=4$ is the perfect illustration of this method: $\{(00,00),(01,10),(10,01),(11,11)\}$.

Hi, to me this is really impressive how someone can come up with something like that so fast. I've marked the answer as accepted, although I am still trying to comprehend it. Do I understand correctly that it is always possible to do with just S points? I was kind of hoping this was impossible, otherwise my reduction from the original problem doesn't really work :,) but the solution is really beautiful. Do you have any idea about the $AB \leq S$ case?

Thanks.  Your picture for $S=4$ really helped (+1) as it had the key idea for $p^n$ there already.  I just had to formalise it.  Dealing with powers of primes separately and then combining is a standard move for this kind of problem.  Yes it is always possible to do with $S$ points.  I suspect you would need more points to get every congruence for $AB\leq S$.  You can post that as a separate question if you like.
